# Reply to all Facebook page comments in 1 go

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have received 10,000+ comments on my Facebook page post. I want to reply to all comments on my Facebook page post in one go.

I want to reply to all persons with the same message. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Facebook want you to grow your page and organically reach your audience with a post on their algorithm, rather than blowing up peoples' notifications. You could reply to some of the top comments, which often gives preview priority to the original page. You could also post your own comment where other users may put it to top comment.

I also wouldn't recommend a script, due to:

> 2. You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.

Although you likely wouldn't get caught with a client-side script with small usage, 10,000 identical comments will definitely get you banned. I wouldn't be surprised if any more than 100 gets your account flagged in the first place. I assume this is for business, and at that point, Facebook will want you to purchase adverts. 10,000 impressions directly into notifications would cost a LOT of money.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. There is no such feature available in Facebook.

Other ways you can write some script which do the task or Create a post with the message referring your *this post*.